# Is two-way repeated-measures ANOVA appropriate in my case?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, two-way

My experimental design is the following.

I have 4 experimental groups, with each drug alone or combination (Control, DrugA, DrugB and DrugA+B) and these treatments were administered after surgery. I run a test before surgery (baseline) and again (on the same subject) after surgery/treatment.

Is two-way repeated-measures ANOVA the appropriate test in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, it sounds like a two-way repeated measures ANOVA (with interaction) is the right choice. Although, if "*Control*" is something other than "*Neither Drug A nor Drug B*", then I would probably run this as a one-way repeated measures design with four treatment levels. I think this can be seen nicely if you represent your factors in as a table such as:

```
                       Drug A
                  No             Yes
            ----------------------------------
Drug B  No  |  Control   |      Drug A       |
            ----------------------------------
       Yes  |   Drug B   |  Drug A + Drug B  |
            ----------------------------------
```

So, if your Control is something else, then this design may not be proper for your experiment.

Comment: Control is indeed "Neither Drug A nor Drug B". I ran the two-way repeated measures ANOVA on graphpad (only program available in all computers in the lab) and DrugA+B is significant compared with Control.

@Jelsema Is there any difference between running this on graphpad and SPSS? Can this 2x2 treatment scheme showing my experimental groups be more accurately shown with SPSS? In graphpad I can just put 4 different treatments and I feel like if they were control plus 3 different drugs the result would have been just the same.

Comment: I have never used GraphPad, and it's been quite a while since I've used SPSS at all, so unfortunately I can't comment on the differences between those programs.

That being said, there can be multiple ways to implement models. Treating this as a two-factor design, or as a one-factor design with 4 treatments, should get the same results. The two-factor design might make some follow-up analyses slightly easier to obtain (e.g., if the model is determined to be significant, assessing the individual drugs, and their interaction).